# how to delete the memory of data member when exception thrown by constructor

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, constructor, destructor, placement-new

I wrote some codes about dealing with exceptions thrown in constructor, by using placement delete to call the destructor to delete the memory of `_pBuf` in order to prevent memory leak.
I'm wondering whether this way is safe to use. Any help is appreciate!

```
//this is an example of throwing exception in constructor,
//and showing how to call the destructor to delete the memory allocated in constructor to prevent memory leak,
//using "placement delete"
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace  std;

class ConWithException
{
public:
    ConWithException() : _pBuf(NULL)
    {
        _pBuf = new int[100];
        cout << "before throw exception in constructor" << endl;
        throw std::runtime_error("Exception in Constructor!");
    }

    ~ConWithException()
    {
        cout << "Destructor!" << endl;
        if( _pBuf != NULL )
        {
            cout <<  "Delete buffer..." << endl;
            delete[] _pBuf;
            _pBuf = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "NULL pBuf" << endl;
        }
        cout << "Destructor end!" << endl;
    }

    void * operator new(size_t size){
        cout << "placement new" << endl;
        return ::operator new(size);
    }

    void operator delete(void* mem){
        cout << "placement delete" << endl;
        ((ConWithException*)mem)->~ConWithException();
        ::operator delete(mem);
    }

    private:
        int* _pBuf;
    };

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
    ConWithException* cwe = NULL;
    try
    {
        cwe = new ConWithException;
    }
    catch( std::runtime_error& e )
    {
        cout<<"exception:"<< e.what() << endl;
    }

    if (cwe == NULL)
    {
        cout << " already NULL, no need to delete" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The usual way to handle exceptions in the constructor is to - if possible - make all the checks that might throw *before* allocating the memory. That way there is no leak whatever happens. Otherwise use RAII and put the resource in a separate class or smart pointer.

Comment: Regardless of the answer to your question, there is no reason here to initialize to NULL in the initialiser list and then to reset to something else inside the body of the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RAII and you don't have to deal with it:

```
class ConWithException
{
public:
    ConWithException() : _pBuf(new int[100])
    {
        cout << "before throw exception in constructor" << endl;
        throw std::runtime_error("Exception in Constructor!");
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> _pBuf;
};
```